# Swap unix compiler flags with a shorter one

Tags: linux, unix, gcc, compilation, flags

I've been running ns3 sumulations in linux and every time I compiled I had to type

```
g++ -Wall -o simulacija simulacija.cc -DNS3_ASSERT_ENABLE -DNS3_LOG_ENABLE `pkg-config --libs --cflags
libns3.16-core-debug libns3.16-network-debug libns3.16-applications-debug libns3.16-internet-debug
libns3.16-point-to-point-debug libns3.16-point-to-point-layout-debug libns3.16-csma-debug
libns3.16-csma-layout-debug libns3.16-topology-read-debug libns3.16-wifi-debug`
```

Is there a way to shorten the flags to eg:

```
g++ -Wall simulacija.cc -o simulacija -my_params
```

Thank you

Comment: Just use a script or a makefile. Or even just a shell variable.

Comment: How would you do it with a shell variable?

Comment: You do that by writing a script that calls the compiler, writing a makefile that does it, or setting an env. var. to your parameters. Look around, there millions of examples of makefiles in particular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GCC compiler supports the `@` notation to embed a sequence of arguments inside a file. Read near end of [GCC overall options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html) page.

So you could put in some file `params.args` the following lines

```
-Wall
-I /usr/local
-DNS3_ASSERT_ENABLE 
-DNS3_LOG_ENABLE
-O
```

and just invoke

```
g++ @params.args  simulacija.cc -o simulacija
```

You could have a `Makefile` rule to build that `params.args`  (e.g. with `pkg-config` etc...)

Actually, it is time to learn how to use [GNU make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/).

Notice that the `@` option is not understood by some other compilers like GCC handles it.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a shell script `myparams.sh` that outputs your parameters:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo -n "-DNS3_ASSERT_ENABLE -DNS3_LOG_ENABLE"
pkg-config --libs --cflags libns3.16-core-debug [...]
```

Now you can run

```
g++ -Wall simulacija.cc -o simulacija `./myparams.sh`
```

(Don't forget to `chmod +x myparams.sh`)

Comment: Also, myparams.sh should be in the same folder where I'm compiling, right?